# Using tableviews for NSData unload

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, http, uitableview

I'm planning on sending my user's contacts to my server via *http* `POST` request, ill then `UTF8` encode the response and parse it into different **NSArrays**. From there I'll use a `UIViewController` containing a container view, embed-linked to a `UITableViewController`, to display multiple tableviews.

The layout is this:  `UIViewController`(containing container view and segmented control on navbar)->{container view-embed link}->`UITableViewController`

I'm pretty sure I can just conditionally load different arrays into the tableviewcells based on the segmented control that is selected. But do I need to make a modular data model for this?

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple i think but if you know how you are going to get data fro array. if you want to load all different data like if you have 4 segment then 4 array so just simply add 4 array property like

```
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSArray *arrayOne;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSArray *arrayTwo;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSArray *arrayThree;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSArray *arrayFour;
@property(nonatomic, retain)  NSArray *dataSource;
```

and set the action in which get the selected index like 0 - 3

and into your dataSource array like

```
if(selectedSengment == 0) {
  dataSource = arrayOne;
  [tableView reloadData];
}
```